# WPF - Can I use a constant for a resource key name?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, styles, key

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type l:MyViewModel}">
    <l:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there any way I can replace the "MyTemplate" with a value from a class of mine?

```
public sealed class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public const string TemplateName = "MyTemplate";

    //I use the TemplateName const to retrieve the correct DataTemplate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about leaving that x:Key and it will be default DataTemplate for your l:ViewModel type ?

not sure if you can Bind/link your key to certain properties

Answer (score 14):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static l:MyTemplateSelector.TemplateName}"
              DataType="{x:Type l:MyViewModel}">
    <l:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```